# Create a ping log with packets sent and lost count result

Tags: windows, batch-file, logging, cmd, ping

I am using a .bat file which log ping test in a log text file.

Right now I have this script.

```
@echo off
:LOOPSTART
echo %time% >> pinglog.txt
ping 192.168.1.1 -n 4 >> pinglog.txt
GOTO LOOPSTART
```

When I run this .bat file then the cmd windows is remains open. And I am trying to get the ping result also in it in the last whenever someone close the cmd windows and .bat file stop running.
Like:

```
ping
ping
ping
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss)
```

Just like Ctrl + C event on closing cmd

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to continue any tasks in a batch by <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> or closing the `batch-file`. It is simply not possible, the script is killed meaning ANYTHING that was supposed to happen has now been terminated in the current process.

There are however other hacks, such as redirecting constant data and when exiting the script by either <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> or exiting by clicking the cross on the top right corner <kbd>X</kbd> the last event captured in the log will remain.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set sent=0 & set received=0 & set lost=0 & set loss=0
:start
for /f "tokens=4,7,10,11delims=,( " %%i in ('ping 192.168.1.1 -n 2 ^| findstr "Packets:"') do (
    set _se=%%i
    set _re=%%j
    set _lst=%%k
    set _lss=%%l
    set _se=!_se:,=!
    set _re=!_re:,=!
    set _lst=!_lst:,=!
    set _lss=!_lss:%%=!
    set /a sent+=!_se!
    set /a received+=!_re!
    set /a lost+=!_lst!
    set /a loss+=!_lss!
)
echo !time: =0! Packets: Sent = !sent!, Received = !received!, Lost = !lost! (!loss! %% loss)>pinglog.log
goto :start
```

Again, it is a hack, but pretty much one of the only few way's you'll achieve what you want.

Comment: How can I create a event when closing the cmd then it store the packets data in last (after all the ping test) which will be the final result of overall ping test.

Comment: And? Did you try it?

Comment: `Ctrl-C` is one thing (@Gerhard: try `ping -t stackoverflow.com` and press `Ctrl-C` after a few lines - Ping will present you a summary). closing the `cmd` window is a completely other thing. OP's request ("I want it to do something after I killed it") is like "I want Windows to do something when I unplug the power". `Cmd` just has no method to "catch" a "Close", like Windows has no method to "catch" a power outage (unless you have a UPS - but that's a different story)

Comment: @Stephan yes, I am aware, so hence this answer. This is the closest he will get to logging something at about the time he closes the window. Closing the window by `x` also logs to the file, but there will always be that possible 2 count gap. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Stephan I do understand what you're saying by means of running `ping stackoverflow.com` from a `cmd`. I however do it differently here, 2 pings, calculate the previous result, then single redirect to file and repeat, so the file will always be closed after writing so it will create a summary at any point you exit the script whether it is ctrl+c or by killing the script.

Answer (score 0):

First Pay attention for naming your batch file as `Ping.bat`

Second you should remove the label `LoopStart` and `Goto LoopStart`

```bat
@echo off
echo %time% >pinglog.txt
ping 192.168.1.1 -n 4 >>pinglog.txt
pause
```

Comment: OP actually wants to just log the total packet data at the time the process gets terminated, which technically is not possible.